# Extracting a data from dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
list1 = ["a","c","d"]
dict1 = {"a":9, "b":2, "c":5, "d":9, "e":6, "f":7 }
```

I want to get only list1's word from dict1.

The following is the result I want to get.

```
{"a":9, "c":5, "d":9}
```

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: `{ key: value for key, value in dict1.iteritems() if key in list1 }`

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a *dictionary comprehension* to do this:

```
>>> list1 = ["a","c","d"]
>>> dict1 = {"a":9, "b":2, "c":5, "d":9, "e":6, "f":7 }
>>> {k: dict1[k] for k in list1}
{'c': 5, 'd': 9, 'a': 9}
```

This works as long as the dictionary keys contains all the items in `list1`, otherwise you may use a filter, to test for items in `list1` that are not in the dictionary:

```
>>> {k: dict1[k] for k in list1 if k in dict1}
{'c': 5, 'd': 9, 'a': 9}
```